# Convert multiples .txt and into a single file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, converters

I have a lot of folders.

In each folder there are aproximally between 1 and 20 .txt-files

Each .txt file (unique name) contain a title (line1) that is followed by a HTML-formatted text (line2)

Example (1) on how a .txt looks inside:

```
Frankfurter tail turkey doner
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet turkey sausage brisket pork.</p><p>Tongue swine turducken capicola shoulder hamburger pig.<p/><p>Ball tip jerky ham, doner <a href=""https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat"">filet mignon ham</a> hock bresaola jowl andouille pig cow</p>
```

Example (2) on how a .txt looks inside:

```
Batman
<p>You either die a hero or you live long enough to see yourself become the villain.</p>
```

Simply explained, I want to merge the content of the .txt files into a single file, that contains one files content per row.

Each line shall shall also be wrapped in quotation marks and a comma be separating them.

From the example above, the output file should look like this:

```
"Frankfurter tail turkey doner","<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet turkey sausage brisket pork.</p><p>Tongue swine turducken capicola shoulder hamburger pig.<p/><p>Ball tip jerky ham, doner <a href=""https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat"">filet mignon ham</a> hock bresaola jowl andouille pig cow</p>"
"Batman","<p>You either die a hero or you live long enough to see yourself become the villain.</p>"
```

So, my question is simply how this is done the easiest and fastest way.

I am doing this by hand right now it's pretty slow, copypasting at this volume makes my brain swell.

Edit1: Been doing some lite research;

- Powershell, VBA and .BAT files seems like something, still havent found anything that works.
- I don't want to have the location of the input or output-files specified in the code, launch file for the solution is to be placed in any folder and output file should also be generated here.

**Try 1#:**
Created a Windows Batch Files (.bat) containing this:

```
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> combined.txt
```

Placed in a folder with a dozen .txt-files, but the console just opens and closes. No file created!

Edit2: Now we are cooking!

This:

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> combined.txt
```

Gives output:

```
Batman
<p>You either die a hero or you live long enough to see yourself become the villain.</p>
Frankfurter tail turkey doner
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet turkey sausage brisket pork.</p><p>Tongue swine turducken capicola shoulder hamburger pig.<p/><p>Ball tip jerky ham, doner <a href=""https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat"">filet mignon ham</a> hock bresaola jowl andouille pig cow</p>
```

This is very close from what I want!

- Now adding quotation marks and replaceing the linebrek with a comma
  is not solved.

Best regards,

Lui Kang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got external help, this works perfectly.

```
    @echo off
cls
setlocal
set "combined=combined.txt"
(
  for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    if not "%%a" == "%combined%" (
      echo %%a 1>&2
      set "firstLine=true"
      for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:   " %%b in ('findstr /n "^" %%a') do (
        if defined firstLine (
          set /p =""%%c",""
          set "firstLine="
        ) else if not "%%c" == "" (
          set /p =%%c
        )
      )
      echo "
    )
  )
) > %combined% <nul
endlocal
goto:eof
```